# FormattedText Width property does not take trailing spaces into account

Tags: c#, wpf, text, formatting, formatted-text

I am using `System.Windows.Media.FormattedText` to do some low level rendering (specifically, trying to render math equations in a typographically pleasing manner). For this, precise metrics on the text blocks I am using are critical.

I am creating several `FormattedText` objects and using these at the lowest level of rendering. The problem is that if any of these contain trailing spaces, that space is not taken into account when computing the `FormattedText.Width` property. For example, if I write:

```
double w1 = new FormattedText ("Hello", ...).Width;
double w2 = new FormattedText ("Hello    ", ...).Width;
```

w1 and w2 turn out to be the same. Leading spaces *are* measured correctly. How do I force `FormattedText` to measure these trailing spaces as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change from using the `Width` property to using the `WidthIncludingTrailingWhitespace` property.

```
double w1 = new FormattedText ("Hello", ...).WidthIncludingTrailingWhitespace;
double w2 = new FormattedText ("Hello    ", ...).WidthIncludingTrailingWhitespace;
```

With this code you should see two different width values.